# Exchange 2007 Open Relay

Tags: email, exchange

Apparently our domain has been spamlisted, and a check has revealed that we're an open relay.

Internally we have just one mail server, Exchange 2007.  No edge transport.

Send connector is configured with Address Space *, cost 1; FQDN same as our MX

Default Receive Connector is same FQDN; authentication is basic only, permission groups are anon, exchange users, exchange servers, legacy exchange.

I don't know how to troubleshoot beyond this.

Comment: How are your accepted domains configured?

Comment: domain.local is default; domain.com is secondary.  both are authoritative

Comment: Are you sure that your Exchange server is the open relay; Exchange 2007+ by default does not allow relaying; so you (or someone) would have had to _make_ it do that.

Comment: normally with an additional receive connector where you can allow certain IPs to be 'externally secured'

Comment: We're getting bouncebacks from our domain from spamfilters, and mxtoolbox.com reported "You may be an open relay".  When I telnet directly into our SMTP, I can authenticate as an arbitrary user, but the email isn't routed.  Perhaps allowing this Sender OK is triggering spam filters that are bouncing from our domain?

Comment: Try without authenticating whatsoever - and send to an external address.  What response line do you get after manually sending a message?

Comment: In connection with what Shane Madden said, maybe you can do a telnet session, with no authentication, and post the session transcript so we can see what's going on.

Comment: [dave@buzzed:~#] telnet mta.domain.com 25      
Trying 66.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to mta.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
e220 mta.domain.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 7 Oct 2011 14:17:47 -0400
hlo
250-mta.domain.com Hello [174.xx.xx.xx]

mail from: derjur@gmail.com
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
rcpt to: derjur@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
dat
500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command
data
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
test
.
250 2.6.0 <473d162b-c5ba-48ec-b8fb-1949d04bbee2@bmexch1.domain.local> Queued mail for delivery

Comment: It says queued, but it doesn't actually send it out.

Comment: Are you on the same subnet when you're doing this as the Exchange machine; if so you might want to try the same from an outside connection.

Comment: It's from an external machine, not connected over vpn. You would get the same results from your machine.

Answer (score 2):

In Exchange 2007/2010 you have to manually enable a receive connector to allow permission for open relay.

Run this against your default send connector (the one that accepts from public address space):

> Get-ReceiveConnector "Your default Receive Connector" | Get-ADPermission -Identity "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON"

If that comes back with ExtendedRights including "ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient" then you have an open relay. You need to remove this permission ASAP using Remove-ADPermission

Comment: Seems it's there.  Ideas on the Remove-ADPermission string to use?

Comment: Get-ReceiveConnector “Your default Receive Connector” | Remove-ADPermission -User “NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON” -ExtendedRights “ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient”